# Can I create a public / private key pair on a mobile device?

Tags: android, ios, security

For now only iOS and Android are important.

The important thing is that I want to create a public/private key pair PER DEVICE. its not about creating the keys during development but during runtime.

Comment: which keys are you reffering to

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/step2.html

Answer (score 0):

On [android](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyPairGenerator.html), this shouldn't be a problem:

```
KeyPairGenerator.getInstance( "RSA" ).genKeyPair();
```